# Emit a signal from another class

Tags: c++, qt

I have this code, structured in 2 *.cpp files and 2 *.h files, and I simply don't understand how to send a signal from one class to another:

I have **mainwindow.cpp**:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "serialcommunication.h"
#include "QDebug"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //other functions;

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    //Here is where I want to emit the signal
    qDebug() << "DONE!";
}
```

This is the **header** for mainwindow.cpp:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
private slots:
    void on_connectButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

};
```

So, I want tot send a signal from mainwindow class to serialcomunication class, to invoke a function here:

Second *.cpp file: **Serialcommunication.cpp**:

```
#include "serialcommunication.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

SerialCommunication::SerialCommunication(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{   
    isStopReadConsoleActivated = false;


    QtConcurrent::run(this,&SerialCommunication::readConsole,isStopReadConsoleActivated);

    }
    void FUNCTION THANT I WANT TO BE CALLED FROM MAINWINDOW CLASS()
    {
//DO SOMETHING
    }
```

And the serialcommunication **header**:

```
class SerialCommunication : public QObject
{
     Q_OBJECT
private:

    //some other fucntions

public:
    explicit SerialCommunication(QObject *parent = nullptr);
     ~SerialCommunication();
};
```

Where I need to put the slot, the signal and the connect method? Thank a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to understand the basic theory about **Slots** and **Signal** which are features of Qt. They allow to any object, inherent from `QOBJECT`, send message between them, like events.

1. The Class which will **emit** an event, must implement a `signal`.

```cpp
//Definition into the Class A (who emits)
signals:
    void valueChanged(int newValue);
```

2. The Class which will receive the event (*signal*), must implement a public `slot` which must have the same argument of the `signal`.

```cpp
//Definition into the Class B (who receives)
public slots:
    void setValue(int newValue);
```

3. The class which will receive the event (*signal*), must connect the *Signal* vs *Slot*. Use the `connect` method to link the *signal*, from and instance of class A, and the slot, from an instance of class B.

```cpp
//There is an instance of class A called aEmit.
void B::linkSignals()
{
   connect(&aEmit, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(setValue(int)));
}
```

4. To trigger the signal use the keyword `emit` with the signal as a functions and its arguments:.

```cpp
//from Class A
void A::triggerSignal()
{
  int myValue{23};
  emit valueChanged(myValue);
}
```

4. In the class B, the method which was declares as slot, shall be invoked.

```cpp
//from Class A
void B::setValue(int newValue);
{
   cout << newValue << endl;
}
```

Here you can see more about the Signals and Slots.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send a signal from the MainWindow to the SerialCom, the signal should be defined in the MainWindow and the slot in SerialCom. From the MainWindow an 'emit' should be called for this signal (probably from the on_connectButton_clicked).
Connecting the signal to the slot should best be done from the MainWindow. The SerailCom object should be known there however to do so. It will be something like (pseudo code):

```
connect(this, signal(sig_name), comm_object, slot(slot_name))
```